# VBS Script to Open Excel and Run Multiple Macros

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am attempting to run the following script in my windows task manager.  My goal is to have the VBScript open the excel file and run two macros at a scheduled time every weekday and then save and close once both macros are performed.  I have tested the VBScript below with limited success; the file opens and the first macro runs but for some reason, the second macro is NOT running (and anything after the second macro isn't running either).  Any suggestions?

```
    Dim objExcel, xlBook

    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("Q:\MyExcelFile.xlsm", 0, False)
    ObjExcel.Application.Visible = True

    objExcel.Application.Run "Module1.Macro1"
    objExcel.Application.Run "Module1.Macro2"


    xlBook.Save
    xlBook.Close True
    set xlBook = Nothing
```

Comment: I also found this online but again, everything works except the second macro and everything that comes after it.

        strMacro1 = "Dat2Excel"
        strMacro2 = "SaveAS2"

        strPath = "Q:\GAS\Hub Pricing\ICE Oil Options\ICE Dat to 
        Excel.xlsm" 
        Set objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
        objApp.Visible = True
        Set wbToRun = objApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath) 
        objApp.Run strMacro1
        objApp.Run strMacro2
        wbToRun.Save 
        wbToRun.Close 
        objApp.Quit

Comment: it could be an issue with your macro.  You should probably post that since the first macro does in fact run.

Comment: Dim FName As String, FPath As String
Dim wkb1 As Workbook, wkb2 As Workbook

Set wkb1 = ThisWorkbook

FileDay = Format$(Day(Range("D3")), "00")
FileMonth = Format$(Month(Range("D3")), "00")
FileYear = Format$(Year(Range("D3")), "0000")

FPath = "Q:\MyFilePath"
FName = "MyFileName_" & FileYear & "_" & FileMonth & "_" & FileDay & ".xls"

Set wkb2 = Workbooks("MyFileName_" & FileYear & "_" & FileMonth & "_" & FileDay & ".dat")
With wkb2
.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & FName
.Close True
End With

ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub

Comment: The comment above is the code for the 2nd macro. For what it's worth, this macro works when I manually run it, but for some reason, it will not work when the task scheduler/vbscript is run.